# Why when I return a false value from a function the parent function gets it as true in php?

Tags: php

I am new with PHP and maybe it is a stupid question but when I use a function to check if a record exists in my database using the following:

```
function isGameExisted($con,$name) 
 {        
     $query = "SELECT * from Games WHERE NAME ='$name' LIMIT 1";
     $check = mysqli_query($con,$query);              
//       var_dump($check);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($check)){

       //echo " EXISTS ";
      return true;
     }else
     {      
     //echo " OFFER DOES NOT EXIST  ";   
     return false;  
     }
 }
```

So far so good it returns false when name does not exist

but in parent function

```
$isExisting = isGameExisted($con,$name);
if($isExisting)
    {

       $json['Result'] = "Fail";
       $json['message'] = "Error in registering. Probably the name already exists";

    }else
    {

    }
```

I am getting true! the message Error in Registering... what I am missing here

thank you

Comment: `isset($check)` will always be true. That's not the way to tell if a query found any matches.

Comment: should I try get number of rows?

Comment: You edited the code and not it doesn't match the question and the answers you already received. The question is useless now for the users that reach this page. You better revert the question to its initial text. Apply the changes suggested in answers to your real code instead.

Comment: Either way it produces the same result

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `isset($check)` is always true. If the query finds a match row, `$check` will be set to an array. If the query doesn't find anything, `$check` will be set to `NULL`.

You should just do:

```
return $check != false;
```

The whole function should be:

```
function isGameExisted($con,$name) 
{        
     $query = "SELECT 1 from Games WHERE NAME ='$name' LIMIT 1";
     $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$query));        
     return $check != null; 
}
```

Comment: When I am passing a new record which its not there so its false but in parent function the $isExisting variable its true

Comment: If it's not there then `$check` is false, so `return $check != false` will return `false`, not `true`.

Comment: Yes thats I am telling you if its false why if($isExisting)
    { } else { } does not go to else part?!?

Comment: ["current_field"]=> int(0)  ["field_count"]=>  int(9) ["lengths"]=>  NULL
            ["num_rows"]=>  int(0)  ["type"]=>  int(0)       }

Comment: That's not right. That looks like what you would get if you did `$check = mysqli_query($query);`, but didn't call `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Comment: var_dump($check); I did it before if(mysql_num_rows($check)){ } else { }

Comment: There's no `mysqli_num_rows()` call in your question.

Comment: It sounds like you made other changes to your function than the one I suggested. I've updated my answer to show the whole thing.

Comment: Neither number of rows nor your updated answer takes me to the else part of my parent function

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Most functions return `FALSE` when they run out of info, this one returns `NULL` instead. I changed the check.

Comment: Again null I've tried $query = "SELECT 1 from Games WHERE NAME ='$name' LIMIT 1"; ,  $query = "SELECT * from Games WHERE NAME ='$name' LIMIT 1"; , $query = "SELECT * from Games WHERE NAME ='Toys' LIMIT 1"; all produce null

Comment: I understand that. Then `return $check != null` should turn that into `false`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try with this

function isGameExisted($con,$name) 
 {        
     $query = "SELECT * from Games WHERE NAME ='$name' LIMIT 1";
     $excQuery = mysqli_query($con,$query);              
     if(mysqli_num_rows($excQuery)){
        //echo " EXISTS ";
          return true;
     }else
     {      
     //echo " GAME DOES NOT EXIST  ";    
     return false;  
     }       
 }
```

Comment: Why do you call `mysqli_fetch_array` if you don't use `$result`?

Comment: Amateur approach I guess

Comment: The question still applies. Changing the order doesn't make a difference.

Comment: If you don't want to fetch the result rows you can comment/remove it.I just kept it there.

Comment: That's what I'm asking: why did you keep it there when it serves no purpose? The whole point of your answer is to call `mysqli_num_rows` **instead** of `mysqli_fetch_array`, isn't it?

Comment: Okk.. I removed it

Comment: I tried the number of rows check  and I get the same again "Error in registering. Probably the name already exists"

Comment: Just print $result = mysqli_fetch_array($excQuery); and check what value it returns.

Comment: This answer is misleading. It mixes [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions with [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions. They don't work together and [the `mysql` PHP extension is dead](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), anyway.

Comment: Srry.. Please use mysqli_num_rows